# Unable to tag SCM when I using maven release plugin

Tags: svn, maven, tags, release, revision

when I using maven release plugin,I encountered some questions,the most one is tag scm failed,the error is :
svn: “svn://192.168.5.222/show/test-show/trunk/show” does not in the revision 0 .

```
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Unable to tag SCM

then I found my log:

[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /data/.hudson/jobs/hxbos/workspace && svn --username liulaixi --password '*****' --no-auth-cache --non-interactive copy --file /tmp/maven-scm-49732292.commit --revision 0 svn://192.168.5.213/hxbos/hxecp-src/trunk/hxbos svn://192.168.5.213/hxbos/hxecp-src/tags/hxbos/hxbos-all-test-1.5.0
[INFO] Working directory: /data/.hudson/jobs/hxbos/workspace

why my --revision is 0？who can help me?thanks!

Comment: Do you have a ../tags folder in svn? Is the SCM url correct in the Maven pom.xml ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I have the tags folder in my svn,I don't know why the svn copy command use the revision 0.My current revision is 4865,but according the log,maven release plugin used revision 0.That's the problem.The log:

Comment: [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /data/.hudson/jobs/hxbos/workspace && svn --username liulaixi --password '*' --no-auth-cache --non-interactive copy --file /tmp/maven-scm-49732292.commit --revision 0 svn://192.168.5.213/hxbos/hxecp-src/trunk/hxbos svn://192.168.5.213/hxbos/hxecp-src/tags/hxbos/hxbos-all-test-1.5.0 [INFO] Working directory: /data/.hudson/jobs/hxbos/workspace

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you don't have the correct svn version. Check installing the most recent and setting it up for your environment. If correct, mvn will be capable of reading this information after uploading pom.xml, and with this will tag the release.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the "tagBase" configuration to your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagBase>https://svn.site.net.br/svn/SiteV6/Vitrine</tagBase>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the error that I checked out only the **trunk** (without **tags** and **branches**).

To my constelation: The svn-repository is stored in `/svn/`. Apache has the `DAV svn` for supporting the `<connection>` tag (not sure if we need DAV) configured like this:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /svn
</Location>
```

And inside the `pom.xml` its:

```
<scm>
    <url>http://www.myproject.com/svn/Project</url>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://www.myproject.com/Project</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn+ssh://root@www.myproject.com/Project</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Then i do

```
svn co file:///svn/Project
cd Project/trunk/
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add   ~/mykey-to-commit-new-tag.ossh
mvn package gpg:sign
svn commit
mvn clean release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.failOnError=false" -X
```

What I really had to do is to checkout the complete project.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to ignore this error and just try mvn release:prepare again? For me it works. Don't ask me why though.